# Using sammy.js with Knockout.js to display single item from url

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, sammy.js

I am trying to accomplish something similar to what is done in the "single page applications" section of the official knockoutjs tutorial, in which I have multiple views working first and then add sammy to make it work off of urls.
In my example, clicking on a name replaced the list view with the single item detail view.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/of73rdxa/2/
If you uncomment line 104:

```
//self.chosenFriend(friend);
```

You can see how I had this working before I tried to introduce sammy and having ids passed from urls. Unfortunately that is no longer what I need because I now want to get the result from the id in the url instead of the clicked event.

the comment out line 112:

```
 //{ name: 'fred', age:  '12' }
```

Shows a static example of the format that will work. Unfortunately my getFriend method is not returning data in the correct format to make this work.

Comment: Just an FYI my company started making SPA's using knockout and we watched a very helpful tutorial from John Papa at pluralsight, http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/spa. Part of the video was an example solution for a code camp he build and in there is a full working KO SPA application using sammy, amplify, require.. Its very sophisticated and helped us a lot. I recommend taking a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that `getFriend().name` and the like wont evaluate to anything because `getFriend()` has no return now and can not be made to return the results of an asynchronous ajax call synchronously.

Instead, you can pass getFriend() a callback so it is in scope for the ajax success function, [like so (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/bs9xfcwe/):

```
self.getFriend = function(id, cb){
var getString = 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/johnbob/friends/' + id;

$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: getString,
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("from getFriend", data); //returns friend id#1
    console.dir(data);
    cb(data);
  }
});
...
Sammy(function() {
    this.get('#:friendId', function() {
      self.getFriend(this.params.friendId, self.chosenFriend);
    });
}).run();
```

Comment: Thanks lossleader, Im not sure if I understand why "getFriend() has no return now" and why passing self.chosenFriend as a callback is fixing the problem?

Comment: So getFriend() is calling $.ajax() with no return statement, so getFriend() is undefined. If you return the result of $.ajax(..) you still aren't returning the data fetched, you are returning the promise to get this data so in either case the caller of getField() can't look at the data, it has to provide a function to receive the data. Here is an example of the promise version: http://jsfiddle.net/bs9xfcwe/1/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation what is the distinction in using

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What is the distinction in using self.getFriend(this.params.friendId).then(self.chosenFriend); with no callback, as opposed to self.getFriend(this.params.friendId,self.chosenFriend); where there is a callback defined in getFriend?

Comment: So in either case you are really setting up a function to be called whenever $.ajax finally has the results of making the request, (which is not when $.ajax() returns to its caller.) Switching from passing in a callback to building on a promise can make intentions clearer and code more general but then readers need to understand a little about promises, i.e. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-lib-compatibility